# Where do I use a css grid in my website

Tags: html, css

I've been developing websites for a while but I'm just now trying to learn about css grids. As I said in the title I need to know where I should actually use the grid in my website. As in should I have on grid that stretches across an entire page (regardless of whether or not I need one) and use smaller grids inside of the main one when I need them. Or should I just use grids in certain places where I need it.

I hope that makes sense. And feel free to include any additional information :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be honest, thats bit like asking what colour should you use for the site :) Its purely a design decision based on what you need and your own preferences, and there is no definitive layout or grid system that would suit everyone.

Comment: Thanks! So it is okay to use it whenever I need it vs across the entire page, right?

Comment: It's not something that you *must* have. You use it when you need it.

Comment: Ok awesome thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into bootstrap3! It will make scaling from mobile to larger devices easy! You can find information regarding the grids bootstrap3 utilizes here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/, once you have it installed and set up in your header you can drop something like this in your body tag to get a feel for how the grid system works, it's very dependent on using containers properly.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Title 1</h2>
        <p class="callouts-desc">
            Title 1 paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Title 2</h2>
        <p class="callouts-desc">
            Title 2 paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Title 3</h2>
        <p class="callouts-desc">
            Title 3 paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Title 4</h2>
        <p class="callouts-desc">
            Title 4 paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Title 5</h2>
        <p class="callouts-desc">
            Title 5 paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <h2>Title 6</h2>
        <p class="callouts-desc">
            Title 6 paragraph, blah blah blah.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

That should prove useful in figuring out and playing around the with bootstrap3 grid system